# Android logcat bluetooth regex

Tags: android, regex, bluetooth, logcat, android-logcat

I am debugging `Bluetooth` on Android and I want to list all avaliable messages related to Bluetooth but I can't find anywhere a list of Bluetooth tags.

```
Is there a `list` available? or a `regex` that allows me to see all messages related to Bluetooth?
```

FYI: `I tried logcat ".*[bB]luetooth.*":V  *:S` but it just outputs

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using non greedy quantifiers on the dot meta-charracter.

```
.*?[bB]luetooth.*?":V *:S
```

Comment: `.*` matches zero or more characters, the most posible while `.*?` does the same but the least possible. The latter "eats" less characters.